# Replace n/a values with conditions in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I am having trouble with replacing N/A values.

My "df" example is as follows, with "OUTPUT" as desired output:

```
ID     NAME    OUTPUT
 A     Coke      Coke
 A      n/a      Coke
 A     Coke      Coke
 A      n/a      Coke
 A     Coke      Coke
 B     Coke      Coke
 B      n/a      Coke
 B      n/a      Coke
 B     Coke      Coke
 B      n/a     Pepsi
 B    Pepsi     Pepsi
 B    Pepsi     Pepsi
 B      n/a     Pepsi
 C   Orange    Orange
 C      n/a    Orange
 D       MD        MD
 D      n/a        MD
 D   Coffee    Coffee
 D      n/a    Coffee
 D      n/a       Tea
 D      Tea       Tea
```

This is just an example. In the actual "df" there are a total of 2212 "NAME" with 6xx,xxx observations. N/A can come in between the names or the start of the name. That's where it gets complicated. Not sure what would be a good approach to achieve this. Some "NAME" could have 3 or 4 names. Each name would have equal amount of n/a values.

Comment: When you read the dataset using `read.table/read.csv`, there is an option with `na.strings` ie. `na.strings='n/a'` would change the `n/a` to `NA`.

Comment: i've changed already 'n/a' to NA :) .. i still need some sort of for loop to give me each individual ID and if an ID only have one NAME, then assign that name to n/a.. but if ID has more than one name, **not sure how i would do it**

Comment: So, if you have changed it to real NAs, it is not clear how some values are changed to 'Coke' and others to 'Pepsi".  For example, the 10th element is Pepsi, I thought it would be 'Coke'

Comment: "proper formatting" is very vague.  What specifically are you looking for?   Also, search here for `[r] fread`

Comment: `df[is.na(df$NAME), ] <- "Coke"`

Comment: That is my problem. NA is not always in between. it can be the starting point. Assumption is for each 1 ID, each name will have equal amount of NAs. I can assign to whatever rows NAs are in equally.

Comment: If positions don't matter, `unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) { indx <- which(is.na(x$NAME)); val <- unique(x$NAME[!is.na(x$NAME)]); x$NAME[indx] <- val; x}), df$ID)`

Comment: Or using `data.table`. `setDT(df)[, NAME1:= NAME][ , NAME1:= replace(NAME1, is.na(NAME1), unique(na.omit(NAME1))) , ID][]`